# Read background FCM message data when coming to foreground Angular PWA

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a Ionic 5 Angular PWA app with integrating FCM with the help of @angular/fire and firebase npm packages. I was able to integrate it successfully and message receiving successfully in foreground and background both. But I need to get all messages data while app in background after user get into the app foreground again. Anyone can suggest me the best approach to do this.

This is my MessagingService class

```
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { NotificationsClient, RegisterPushTokenVm } from 'src/app/api-proxy/medcollector-api';

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
    currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging, private notificationsClient: NotificationsClient) {

        this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
            (_messaging) => {
              _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
              _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
            }

          )
    }

    requestPermission() {
        this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(async (token) => {
            const tokenVm = new RegisterPushTokenVm();
            tokenVm.token = token;
            await this.notificationsClient.register(tokenVm).toPromise();
            console.log(token);
        }, (err) => {
            console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
    }

    receiveMessage() {
        this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload) => {
            console.log('new message received. ', payload);
            this.currentMessage.next(payload);
        })
    }
}
```